# Windows 7 - RDP icon on taskbar - can I have more choices?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, taskbar, jumplist

I am running Windows 7 and I added a remote desktop icon pinned to the desktop taskbar.

If I "drag it up" I get 10 recent "session" choices.

Can I get more than 10 somehow?  Registry change?

Comment: This isn't posted as an Answer because it doesn't answer your question, but you might be interested in Terminals.  It's an open source .NET Remote Desktop app.  It has History, you can configure Favorites, and it allows you to maintain several open connections simultaneously.  Plus, it does RDP, VNC, SSH, VMRC, Citrix, ... http://www.codeplex.com/Terminals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're seeing the Remote Desktop Connection **jump list** (a new feature in Windows 7).

Here's how you change the number of items in the jump lists (which defaults to 10):

[Change Number of Recent Items in Windows 7 Taskbar Jump List](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/change-number-of-recent-items-in-windows-7-taskbar-jump-list/)